# SizeToContent not working after Window is Loaded

Tags: c#, wpf

This is probably a silly question and I'm probably missing something simple, but here's the details:

I would like to resize my window only under some condition. It seems when the window is already rendered, SizeToContent doesn't work. I've tried invalidating and updating the layout, but both don't work.

Pertinent code:

```
public void Initialize(...)
{
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(OnLoaded);
}

void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Loaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(OnLoaded);
    Window win = Infragistics.Windows.Utilities.GetAncestorFromType(this, typeof(Window), true) as Window;

    if (win != null)
    {
        if (condition) // this is my condition ("just checks a property")
        {
            win.Topmost = true;
            win.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
            win.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
        }
    }
}
```

So I guess my question is: If you give a window a pre-defined size (something big, for instance, 600x400), and once rendered, you want to use SizeToContent to fit the window to the content (which is much smaller, maybe like 100x50), is this possible?

Comment: The SizeToContent property is working in my tests, both during and after the Loaded event has fired.  Perhaps the visual tree of your window is preventing the measured size of content from propagating up to the top level window?  You might need to edit your question to include some XAML describing your visual tree.

Comment: @RogerN thanks for taking a deeper look! Unfortunately, this control is pretty abstracted from my view (since its part of a business application), so I actually don't even know how the xaml is particularly constructed. I think I have some ideas on how I can fix this, I think I may be able to set the desired size before the Loaded event is fired. We have some APIs that support this, and maybe that's the direction I'll go in. Thanks again!